# JavaScript: cross site request on localhost on ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, cross-domain, jsonp, asp.net-web-api2

I have an ASP.NET WebAPI application running on

```
http://localhost:13057/worldwind
```

I have another ASP.NET MVC5 application running on

```
http://localhost:2425/worldwind
```

When the client code on the MVC5 application attempts the following AJAX call:

```
 $.ajax(http://localhost:13057/worldwind/images, 
            {                
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                error: Utilities.Logger.displayAjaxError,
                success: this.onImagesRetrieved,
                context: this               
            });
```

I get error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:13057/worldwind/api/images. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:2425' is therefore not allowed access.
```

If I change the dataType in the AJAX request to jsonp, the WebAPI is being invoked even though I get error

> jQuery18209344927002675831_1412452833242 was not called

How do I get this thing working?

Comment: The easiest would be to host both on the *same* domain (hostname + port). But if they are to be separate-hosted in production, maybe consider CORS/XDR. If you get the *warning* that "{the JSONP callback} was not called" then it is likely that the JSONP *response* is invalid; maybe it is still returning normal JSON or is using the wrong function name? In any case, viewing the raw response will clear up that issue.

Comment: Thanks for response.  Ideally, I will like both applications to be hosted separately.  Will look into CORS/XDR.  Now, I am getting an error that the jsonp callback was not called.  Is there something I should be changing on my service to support jsonp?

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to do so *standard* with the ASP.NET Web API but there are custom MediaTypeFormatters and/or handling an IHttpHandler wrapper, perhaps. (That is, it is a solved problem with several implementations available online.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up enabling CORS following instructions from [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

This involved 3 steps (well, after fighting with other NuGet upgrade issues):

1. Adding NuGet package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
2. Adding the following lines in WebApiCconfig.Register static method:

   ```
       var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://locahost:2425", "*", "*");
       config.EnableCors(cors);
   ```
3. Rebuilding and running.

Answer (score 0):

if your .jsp put in

```
http://localhost:13057/MySite/JSONP.jsp
```

use your script section like this:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src="http://localhost:13057/MySite/JSONP.jsp?callback=jsonHandler"></script>
```

hope it will be help.